# How to fix 'No static field INSTANCE of type Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier'?

Tags: android, amazon-sns

I've got an Android app to which I'm trying to add Google Cloud Messaging services using AWS' SNS service. The app worked fine before I started. I then added these dependencies:

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.0.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-ktx'
implementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:sns:+'
```

I'm able to write the code I need (following published examples). However when I try to instantiate the SnsClient, my app blows up with this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field INSTANCE of type Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier; in class Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier;
```

I did not intentially try to use any classes from the org.apache.http packages so I assume that one of the other dependencies I added uses it. Which means I can't solve the problem by using some other http package.

What is the root cause of this problem and how do I fix it?

Frank

Comment: Are you sure that `software.amazon.awssdk:sns` is designed for use on Android?

Comment: As far as I understand, Android can work with Java code whether or not it was intended for Android.

Comment: Also, I have an iOS app that uses the same method to access SNS. It looks like Amazon offers an Android-specific sdk called “Amplify” but that doesn’t appear to support SNS.

Comment: I think that the missing INSTANCE field was deprecated and removed from Apache http, which is apparently what Amazon is using to make http requests. So I think the best solution would be for the Amazon code to be updated. Is the source code available so I can do this myself?

Comment: "As far as I understand, Android can work with Java code whether or not it was intended for Android" -- not generally. The Java JDK, for various versions, contains lots of things that are not in the Android SDK.

Comment: True, but at least in this case, the thing that's stopping it from working is trivial.

Comment: "the thing that's stopping it from working is trivial" -- you only know of the *first* thing that is stopping it from working. There may be others. Note that the specific thing that you are lacking (`AllowAllHostnameVerifier`) is gone for a very good reason: it is a security flaw. If you add it, your app is likely to be rejected for distribution on the Play Store, if that matters to you. "Is the source code available so I can do this myself?" -- not that I am aware of.